# Calling Specflow from LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad, specflow

Does anyone have any examples / tutorials of calling Specflow from LinqPad?

I was just thinking that it would be useful for experimenting with pre-populated mocks.

A quick Google search didn't find anything.

Comment: Have a look for Fitnesse or Concordian, these are tools specifically for playing with the data and trying out the test scenarios.

Comment: Thanks @AlSki I hadn't come across those tools before.